# What is meant by 'to kill game?' (5:95)

Tags: quran, tafseer, hadith-interpretation

Surah al ma'idah (5:95)

O  believers! **Do not kill game while on pilgrimage. Whoever kills game** intentionally must compensate by offering its equivalence—as judged by two just men among you—to be offered at the Sacred House, or by feeding the needy, or by fasting so that they may taste the consequences of their violations. Allah has forgiven what has been done. But those who persist will be punished by Allah. And Allah is Almighty, capable of punishment.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Game has also this meaning, I hope it is clear now.
[image]

Comment: Ohh thank you very much